# VB.NET: How can I remap the soap.location property of a web service at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have a web application I'm deploying at multiple clients.  Each client will be consuming a web service that was developed by a third party and is hosted at each client location.  The soap.location will be different for each deployment.

I am looking to avoid having to do separate compiles foe each client.

[This blog post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/steve.hebert/archive/2007/11/13/manually-mapping-wsdl-soap-address-location-on-the-fly.aspx) has a potential solution but is missing a crucial element; how to make the client use the derived class for the soap calls.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Your calling the same webservice hosted on different url's correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check [How can I dynamically switch web service addresses in .NET without a recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125399/how-can-i-dynamically-switch-web-service-addresses-in-net-without-a-recompile#125424)