# How to add a dynamic link for a service reference endpoint in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, service-reference

I'm trying to define a service endpoint in my web.config file so that I can point our staging build to a staging web service and a different end point for production. There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125399/how-can-i-dynamically-switch-web-service-addresses-in-net-without-a-recompile) that deals with *web references* in Visual Studio 2005/2008. I'm adding a **service reference** and can't seem to find anything in properties that would allow me to define the Url Behaviour as dynamic.

I'd like to define the url in the appSettings. Does anyone know how this works in Visual Studio 2010 for Service References?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the end point using what is known as a config transformation.

In short, a config transformation allows you to tweak various config settings depending on your deployment.  This is a technique commonly used for changing connection strings as well.

Here's more reading:  [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx)

Comment: Ah, hadn't realised it put the endpoint in the web.config. Thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the URL at run time just after you create the web service but before you use it:

```
string localUrl = "localhost";
string stagingUrl = "http://staging.example.com"
string url = Request.IsLocal ? localUrl : stagingUrl;

var _webService = new YourWebService { Url = url };
```

Comment: Can't see a URL property on the class generated for my ServiceReference.

Comment: I also can't find a Url property on the Service Reference. Maybe this sample code was written for a web reference?