# How do I configure and initialize a .NET 2.0 SOAP web-reference manually?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I added a .NET 2.0 web reference with the Visual Studio IDE, but for this specific case it can't be configured using the app.config file.

So I tried to initialize it this way:

```
var service = new MyWebservice
{
   Url = config.MyWebserviceUrl
};
```

But I get the following exception:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString

`config.MyWebserviceUrl` contains a valid web address.

What is the correct way to configure and initialize a webservice programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the `URL Behavior` setting for the web reference? If it's `Dynamic`, it will be attempting to get the URL from the config file.

This question covers programmatic configuration of the URL in more detail:

[How can I dynamically switch web service addresses in .NET without a recompile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125399/how-can-i-dynamically-switch-web-service-addresses-in-net-without-a-recompile)