# C# How to change service reference on publish

Tags: c#, replace, deployment, publish, service-reference

I'm using Service Reference based on wsdl:

```
https://webapi.allegro.pl.webapisandbox.pl/service.php?wsdl
```

to get data from sandbox enviroment. Everything works fine but I need to change it on publish to production enviroment:

```
https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php?wsdl
```

I don't like to do it manually before each publish, so how to do it automatically?
It's possible using web reference, but I need to do it with service reference.

Comment: should be in the web.config file

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125399/how-can-i-dynamically-switch-web-service-addresses-in-net-without-a-recompile

Set the service property to dynamic

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/5BELpLk.png) there is only one property (Folder Name)

Comment: add it as a web reference not a service reference

Comment: According this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158270/4680550 web reference is deprecated, so is there any way to do it using service reference?