# generate webservice in Visual Studio with a dynamic root URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap

I want to create a C# application that communicates with two SOAP webservices. These webservices (WSDL files) use the same url

```
<root>/...dirPath.../dms.cfc?wsdl
<root>/...dirPath.../cobra.cfc?wsdl
```

`<root>` should be dynamic because the application user has to set this variable.

First of all I took this

[How can I dynamically switch web service addresses in .NET without a recompile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125399/how-can-i-dynamically-switch-web-service-addresses-in-net-without-a-recompile)

and tried this

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

Further I found this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/setting-the-url-property-of-the-web-service?view=sql-server-2017

but these links didn't help I can't find the settings `URL behaviour` and I can't access the URL property by code.

I created a static class that should handle both webservices. The user is able to change the webservice root url.

An example URL would be

`http://localhost:8500/CoBRA/...dirPath.../dms.cfc?wsdl`

or

`http://myInstance.com/CoBRA/...dirPath.../dms.cfc?wsdl`

handled by this code

```
public static class CoBRAService
    {
        private static cobraClient cobraBaseClient = new cobraClient();

        private static dmsClient cobraDmsClient = new dmsClient();

        public static void SetWebserviceRootUrl(string rootUrl)
        {
            // cobraBaseClient.url = $"{rootUrl}/path/dms.cfc?wsdl";
            // cobraDmsClient.url = $"{rootUrl}/path/cobra.cfc?wsdl";
        }
    }
```

Both webservices don't inherit from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` they implement this `public partial class cobraClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyProject.CoBRA_Base.cobra>, MyProject.CoBRA_Base.cobra`

This is my project structure

[image]

Where can I set the webservice url or how can I access the url property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your  "CoBRA_BaseClient" and "CoBRA_DMSClient" inherited from *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase< TChannel >* 
then you can try the following:

```
public static CoBRA_BaseClient CreateService()
{
    CoBRA_BaseClient service = new CoBRA_BaseClient();
    service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("uri");
    return service;
}

public static CoBRA_DMSClient CreateService()
{
    CoBRA_DMSClient service = new CoBRA_DMSClient();
    service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("uri");
    return service;
}
```

Comment: No sorry. They are set up with `public partial class cobraClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyProject.CoBRA_Base.cobra>, MyProject.CoBRA_Base.cobra`